# How to integrate various content types in one page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-login

I like to make a site that people register, and then login  and in one page tell other people about them selves.
Using some plugins I created some content types like: My job, My life, My family, A brief about me...
Now I need to make a page that people fill all this content types about them selves in that page.
I am not sure that making a form is the best way to do this. Please help me to find the best way of making my desired page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make myAccount page with custom template, and allow user to rich on that page only if they lodged in, and on that page you can show the, that user previous info, and then way to edit or fill that info,
just like following website http://smarthosting.rs/drone/profile/sima/ this link display profile info as you have, then if that user is lodged in they can edit there info,
[image]